# C# - make it so only the same instance can modify its properties/call methods?

Tags: c#, .net, lua, monogame

I am making a game engine with the MonoGame Framework. Since this is a multiplayer game, other players need to know certain information about other players, such as position and velocity, typically for AI reaction.

I am about to implement Lua scripting for player actions. However, I can't currently think of a way to have it so a player cannot *modify* the other players' information, such as position and name.

For instance, say I have the following property in C#:

```
public Vector2 Pos { get { return pos; } private set { this.pos = value; } }
private Vector2 pos;
```

Looks good, right? Well not quite. Say I have a function that returns the closest enemy called `GetNearestEnemy()`, which returns another Player. Because the Player class has access to its own properties, I can just as easily do something like this in some other method:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    Player otherPlayer = GetNearestEnemy();
    otherPlayer.Pos = new Vector2(34,151);
}
```

So I think "maybe I could just pass the instance as a parameter."

```
public void SetPos(Player instance, Vector2 pos)
{
    if (instance != this)
        return;
    else
        this.pos = pos;
}
```

... and always pass "this" as an argument. However, that also has the same problem: I could just as easily pass `GetNearestEnemy()` to the method and I'd be able to set the enemy position.

This is the type of behavior I am trying to prevent. Is there a way to preferably either:

1. Get the instance that called the method?
2. Implicitly set a parameter from the calling object without them knowing?

Or is there some other way to approach it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I don't think `otherPlayer.Pos = new Vector2(34,151);` should work - did you actually test it?

Comment: No, there is no language support for dealing with what you want here. Presumably, since you're writing this class, you're making sure it won't do something it shouldn't.

Comment: @MetaColon Yes. Since DoStuff is a method within Player, it has access to everything the Player class does.

Comment: @tayoung I see.

Comment: Make `GetNearestEnemy` return a clone of source reference.  That way any modifications are performed on the clone and will not be able to modify the source reference.

Comment: Under the assumption that the same programmer do both classes, this is just part of the design. If there are two competitive programmers, there is no way a language feature will prevent them from accessing state within the same process. The CLR however has some isolation features like app domains (full .NET Framework only). (See .NET terrarium)

Comment: Access modifiers are not a security mechanism. The typical way of strongly suggesting that one piece of code should access an object only in certain ways is to pass around references typed as interfaces.

Comment: C# as a language appreciates classes more than objects. It does not support what you want as a language. In C# my car can remove the engine from your car because they are of the same class. Unfortunately there are not too many languages that support object centered encapsulation btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

There is no language support for what you want.

Let me be specific about what you want just so that you understand what I answered.

Your question is basically this: Given that I have *two* instances of an object, and I have properties in this object that have a private setter, is there any language support for ensuring that instance #1 cannot change this private information of instance #2?

And the answer is no.

This will compile and "work":

```
public class Test
{
    public void TestIt(Test t)
    {
        t.Value = 42;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

...
var t1 = new Test();
var t2 = new Test();
t1.TestIt(t2); // will "happily" change t2.Value
```

Basically, the onus is on *you* to make sure this doesn't happen if you don't want it to happen. There is no language or runtime support to prevent this.

The access modifiers you can use are:

- `public`: Anyone can access this
- `private`: Only the type can access this
- `protected`: Only the type, or a descendant of the type, can access this
- `internal`: Any type *in the same assembly* can access this
- `internal protected`: Any type *in the same assembly* **or** a descendant, can access this

Other than this, you have no other options. So "only the same **instance** can access this" does not exist as an access modifier.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. After a bit more thinking, I suppose what I should do instead of returning a whole player instance in methods like that is to return a struct that contains read-only copies of the values they want to look at. That way, player objects in scripts CAN get the info they want from other players, but they cannot set them. Thanks for the info!

Comment: You actually can achieve this with closures but you need to use some variant of `IDictionary<string, object>`, such as an expando object. You will not have type system support but it is possible to model instance level privacy using closures.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. If `Pos` is a property with a private setter (as it is) the only way they could change it would be by calling a public method from within `otherPlayer`. Something like `otherPlayer.SetPos(new Vector2(34,151))`, where `SetPos()` is:

```
public void SetPos(Vector2 NewPos)
    { Pos = NewPos; }
```

Comment: It does work since DoStuff is a method within Player. Thus it has access to everything the Player class does.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the property and you are worried about being set from elsewhere:

```
public Vector2 Pos { get { return pos; } private set { this.pos = value; } }
private Vector2 pos;
```

This will NOT work. So you do not need to worry:

```
Player otherPlayer = GetNearestEnemy();
otherPlayer.Pos = new Vector2(34,151); // <--- no this will not work
```

That property can only be set from within the class.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. The latter can be done within the class, which is what I don't want to happen from other instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The original scenario posted can be handled using an interface e.g. IPeerPlayer that only exposes what other players should see and hides other properties (i.e. the other properties would not be in the IPeerPlayer interface.)